# Where should I tell WordPress where error_log messages should be written?

Tags: debug, wp-debug

I have two different instances of the same server (one for development, one for deployment), built independently but basically the same (same OS, same WordPress version, same content etc.).

However, I'm confused about the configuration: it looks to me like they're configured the same (except that the deployment server is told not to write errors/warnings to the browser).

Both configurations specify `ini_set( 'error_log', '/var/log/wp-debug.log' );` and that file is indeed created by both; however, on one server anything written using `error_log(...)` goes to `/var/log/wp-debug.log` whereas on the other server, such output instead goes to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (although PHP errors and warnings go to `/var/log/wp-debug.log`).

I've tried playing with the defined values of `WP_DEBUG`, `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` as well as changing what `display_errors` is set to via `ini_set(...)` but nothing seems to make any difference.

Can I specify somewhere that I want the output of `error_log(...)` calls to go to one or other of these logs?  (I'd like the output always to go to the Apache `error.log` because that extra information I want to use.)

Comment: Where and when are you setting your `ini_set`? It looks like and that second server, the `ini_set` is ignored (or simply not set) and `error_log()` is using your web servers default location.

Comment: Both `ini_set`s for `log_errors` are done in the same place on each server, which is in `wp-includes/load.php`.  (And before anyone says anything... yes, I know I shouldn't modify anything inside `wp-includes`!  Best practice aside, both should really behave the same.)

Comment: You are right, they should behave the same given that no other server configuration are the same.  Have you double checked your `htaccess` file, your `server-available` configuration and your `php.ini` file for any overriding settings or misconfigurations?  Other than that I don't see why it's not working the same on both machine.  Did Rarst answer fix your issue?  I would of suggested the same thing.

Comment: Ultimately, the simplest solution was to add `ini_restore('error_log');` to the end of my `wp-config.php` file.  That way, I no longer need to be naughty and change the settings in `wp-includes/load.php` and don't need to _try_ to send the output to apache2's `error.log`: that's the default so restoring the value does the trick.  Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described elsewhere on this page, in my case the solution was simply to reset the value of PHP's `error_log` setting.  I did this by adding to the end of my `/var/www/html/wp-config.php`:

```
ini_restore('error_log');
```

One important point: I ended up putting this right at the end because it didn't seem to take effect when included just after the various `define('WP_DEBUG...', ...);` lines.

Thanks to **Rarst** and **bynicolas** for their advice, which helped lead me to this solution.

Answer (score 3):

On WP side the only handling it does is setting log to `WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log'` if `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is enabled (highly bad idea in production environment as public location). If I remember right the very early implementations of this constant allowed to customize the path, but that's no longer the case.

In my experience `ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 ); ini_set( 'error_log', '/path' )` in `wp-config.php` should be sufficient (if you don't enable `WP_DEBUG_LOG` which will override it).

Your second case sounds strange. I would expect errors to go one destination or another, but not to two separate log files. It might be that something *changes* the configuration during runtime. It's impossible to say without hands on troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst, I'm glad you agree it's strange!  I found your comment about `WP_DEBUG_LOG` interesting: I hadn't considered that this might be another way of configuring PHP's behaviour, I assumed they were two separate layers of configuration.  I'm now wondering what would happen if I completely unset this part of the config... Would it default to going into Apache's error log instead?

Comment: Yes, if it's unset it should go to Apache log, see http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: Thanks again.  Indeed it did!  I still have no idea why the original configuration works for one server but not for the other but this is a good workaround.